# spring (Roo) + JCR (Jackrabbit..)

Tags: spring, spring-roo, jackrabbit, jcr

I want to develop an application with an admin tool to manage the content (articles...) of the website...I would like to use SPRING (ROO) but I do not know if there is any JCR API working with it ? I heard a lot about Jackrabbit...Is it possible to create an application with an intereaction between Jackrabit and SPRING ?

Or do SPRING include any tool to manage the content repository ? Optional question is should it integrate some feature to interact with other 'workflow technology' (because I want an edit/validete/publish process) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provide some JCR API abstractions. But even if they does not exist, you could use Jackrabbit, and Spring will just ignore it.

But I do not know if there is a Spring ROO, JCR module.

Comment: I am discovering these tecnologies. ROO is OSGi compatible and I have seen that Sling (technology done at the upper level of Jackrabbit) communicate also with OSGi. Is OSGi the solution of the problem (OSGi can do the intereaction between SPRING architecture and Sling (and maybe Jackrabbit) architecture) ?

Comment: @nazero: see: http://www.infoq.com/articles/spring-modules-jcr -- it is a bit old, but may it help you. - I do not have so much OSGI knowledge, to provide a valid statement for your Sling, Spring, Roo, Osgi question.